# Need IFTTT recipe to send specific gmail attachments to specific dropbox folders

Tags: gmail, dropbox, recipe, ifttt

For example: Email arrives with subject "Report for domaina.com". It has an attachment. I want to setup the recipe to save domainareport.pdf to Dropbox under /reports/Domaina. I'd then create similar recipes for domainb, domainc, etc. Seems like this is possible, but I'm a total IFTTT nub. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a trigger on gmail using email from search and typing in this
[image: Try This]
Create an action using Dropbox and it will have automatically filled 
out everything EXCEPT the folder path edit the folder path so it looks like this
[image: Use This]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't use the attachment filename because it's dynamic. I have to be able to filter based on the subject of the email and then send the attachment it a specified Dropbox folder. Any way to do that? Thanks!